# Cannot retrieve stereotypes from UML model generated using Papyrus with Acceleo

Tags: dsl, modeling, acceleo, papyrus

I am currently testing out the DSL capabilities of Papyrus in combination with Acceleo and I am currently encountering a problem.

I created a simple [relational database metamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjUl6.png) using UML 2 profiles with Papyrus. I then created a [gruesome library model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZlpc.png) using the meta-model defined.

Then I created a very very simple Acceleo template file, in which I try to print some elements' stereotypes :

```
[template public generateElement(p : Package)]
[comment @main/]
[file (p.name.concat('_debug.txt'), false, 'UTF-8')]
Creating file for package [p.name/]
Stereotypes: [for (st : Stereotype | p.getAppliedStereotypes()) separator(',')][st.name/][/for]
[/file]
[/template]
```

When I use the OCL console on my model, "getAppliedStereotypes()" works just fine. But when I run my Acceleo, there is nothing behind "Stereotypes", even though the generator terminates without any error code...

Do you have any idea what is going on ?

Comment: see https://github.com/arcadien/spbcg for a sample implementation

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the same issue as I pointed out for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229639/how-to-check-sysml-stereotypes-with-acceleo/44430428#44430428). Acceleo generations operate in stand-alone mode, so you have to actually tell it where to find the profile you're using.

The [Acceleo FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/FAQ#How_can_I_use_UML_profiles_with_my_generator.3F) has some examples with "standard" profiles, you will have to follow the same process for your own defined profiles.